# Excel formula to pull data from last 5 rows of a cell range that has new rows added daily

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As the title suggests, I have a worksheet (sheet1) that has lots of data that spans columns A-E and with rows that are added daily, What I want to do is on a separate worksheet (sheet2) show the data from the last 5 rows of sheet1.

Comment: Numbers, text or a mix of both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an appropriate cell on Sheet2, use this formula,

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MATCH(1E+99, Sheet1!$A:$A)-(ROW(1:1)-1))
```

Fill right for a total of 5 columns then fill those 5 cells down 5 rows.

That formula will find the last number in a column. This is often the case as the left-most column mat hold an ID number. The same reference point should be used to collect cell values from other columns to avoid the confusion that a rogue blank cell would create.

If all you have are text values then the formula in the first cell would be,

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MATCH("žžž", Sheet1!$A:$A)-(ROW(1:1)-1))
```

Fill right and down as described above.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it but while `zzz` would likely be more than sufficient, `žžž` does actually sort to a higher order than `zzz` and it is the highest possible sort order that you are looking for. In other words, you want to look for something that cannot be found. When Excel cannot find a match it returns the last place looked; i.e. the last text value in the column.

Comment: Thanks for that Jeeped, but it's returning an #N/A error?

Comment: If Sheet1!A:A has numbers, use the first one with `1E99`; if it has text or numbers-that-are-actually-text-and-not-real-numbers then use the second one with `žžž`.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to pull the data, does it matter that the data in the cells it is trying to pull from is a formula?

Comment: No, the manner that the value is delivered to the worksheet does not matter; it can be typed, imported, linked or from a formula. Have you considered posting several rows of redacted sample data? Take a look at [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/last_number_or_text.xlsb).

Comment: If you have the formula working as Sheet1 then just change the worksheet name on the worksheet tab. The formula will automatically change. The name change will not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Providing there is continuous data within column A on Sheet1, you could also use the [`INDIRECT()`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) and [`COUNTA()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTA-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) functions.

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$"&COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-4)
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$"&COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-3)
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$"&COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-2)
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$"&COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1)
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$"&COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))
```

You would need to amend the column letter within the INDIRECT function for each column of data which you wish to view on Sheet2.

Comment: This doesn't seem to pull the data, does it matter that the data in the cells it is trying to pull from is a formula?